# How to set a key prop in a select element

Tags: reactjs

I've created a stateless component and passed in props. But however in the browser I get this error: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

This is what I Have tried.

```
const OptionItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <option key={props.customerId} value={props.customerValue}>
            Code: {props.customerCode} Name: {props.customerName}
        </option>
    );
};

const selectOptions = (props) => {
    const customers = props.consumers.map((customer) => {
        return (
            <OptionItem
                customerId={customer._id}
                customerValue={customer.name}
                customerCode={customer.customer_code}
                customerName={customer.name}
            />
        );
    });
    return (
        <select
            value={props.SelectElementValue}
            onChange={props.selectCustomerHandler}
        >
            {/* <option key="1" value="1" disabled>
                Select Customer
            </option> */}
            {customers}
        </select>
    );
};
```

And then passed it down to another stateless component

```
<SelectItem
 consumers={props.customers}
 SelectElementValue={props.defaultValue}
 selectCustomerHandler={props.customerSelectHandler}
 />
```

And finally linking it to the state component

```
<ModalContent
 dateLabel={this.state.dateLabel}
 customers={this.state.customers}
 defaultValue={this.state.selectCustomerDefault}
 customerSelectHandler={this.customerSelect}
/>
```

What is expect is that i should be able to use the `customer._id` from the database as my `key`

But unfortunately I got an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your OptionItem component appears to me to be the one that requires the key. You are creating and assigning them to the customers variable and then inserting them into your select element. Try adding the key in the consumers.map() like below.

```
const OptionItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <option key={props.customerId} value={props.customerValue}>
            Code: {props.customerCode} Name: {props.customerName}
        </option>
    );
};

const selectOptions = (props) => {
    const customers = props.consumers.map((customer) => {
        return (
            <OptionItem
                key={customer._id} //I BELIEVE THIS IS THE MISSING KEY
                customerId={customer._id}
                customerValue={customer.name}
                customerCode={customer.customer_code}
                customerName={customer.name}
            />
        );
    });
    return (
        <select
            value={props.SelectElementValue}
            onChange={props.selectCustomerHandler}
        >
            {customers}
        </select>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you it work, I've learned something new today. Please keep up the good work.

Comment: I get the instinct to put the key in the option being returned by OptionItem but as far as React is concerned, its the OptionItem that is in the list (and each OptionItem contains only one Option) so that is where the key goes. Basically, if a map is returning a list of components, that's where the key goes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this warning is because the component you're rendering inside the map needs a key. More information about keys is found at the React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

From the docs, the best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys. So in your example, the `customer._id` could work.

For example:

```
const customers = props.consumers.map((customer) => {
        return (
            <OptionItem
                key={customer._id}
                customerId={customer._id}
                customerValue={customer.name}
                customerCode={customer.customer_code}
                customerName={customer.name}
            />
        );
    });
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this has been down voted? It's the exact same answer as the "accepted best answer" just with a link to the docs and none of the unrelated code, posted 3 minutes after it. Is there something wrong with the solution that I've missed?

Comment: I'll give you an upvote to balance it out, because the answer is definitely not wrong. Sometimes the downvoting behaviour seems to be for no reason at all.

Comment: Not downvoted but if it only adds a link, it should be a comment to the OP question or the answer

Comment: Yes but when I was writing this and posted it, the accepted answer had not been posted. Once I refreshed my browser/came back to the page only then did I see (3 minutes earlier) an answer had been posted. I also dont think deleting this on that basis is correct.

Comment: @CalIrvine upvoting for balancing is wrong: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-it-wrong-to-use-an-upvote-to-balance-out-a-downvote

Comment: The upvote wasn't to balance though even though it has. The answer I gave was not wrong, it was in fact correct - why would this have warranted a downvote in the first place? The vote was given by Cal because the answer is correct.

Comment: @AntonioBuelli I was upvoting because this was a correct answer with a negative score, which makes it look like an incorrect answer. It is a good answer with correct information, and therefore I think my upvote is justified. But thanks for the info, I will definitely keep it in mind.